# Populate form using AJAX in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ujs

I'm new to rails and would like to use AJAX to update the a form's text fields after a value has been placed into a key text field.

I see it's possible to create an event handler using something like:

```
:onchange => remote_function(...)
```

but this doesn't feel like it gels with the concept of UJS. Is there another way I can populate the fields in place and delay creating the record until the Submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a blur/change/whichever you want handler on the text field in question.

Make the Ajax request, send JSON back, populate the fields as appropriate.

Comment: Right, I see that I CAN do that but my question is really whether this is an acceptable way to go, the only way to go, or if there are more UJS friendly alternatives...

Comment: @BrMcMullin How is that not UJS? You don't have to use `:onclick` in the tag itself, you can attach it normally on doc ready.